# Tomcat server doesn't compile jsp

Tags: java, linux, jsp, tomcat, debian

I installed tomcat on my Linux server and it worked well.

Recently I had some problems with it and it doesn't run at start of my server anymore.

I recreate manually some scripts in init.d and my tomcat works now.

But now if I create a new jsp file, it will not be compiled by tomcat anymore. Even if I delete the work/... directory...

What daemon/script should I run at start to get my tomcat compiling again my jsp ?

EDIT

my problems was that tomcat wouldn't run at boot anymore. I rewrote the startup.sh, which is the script I was talking about. I remember I had to chmod by myself the script and I'm not sure I did it well but tomcat run at boot now.

To give more detail, I can explain that I created a new directory in my webapps folder (we can call it "project") and I created a jsp in this project. The jsp compiled well.
Then the I created the new jsp (which one I was talking about in my first subject) into the same folder by copying the old jsp and renaming it. But when I tried to display it in my browser it gave me an error 404.
I made some research and I learned that when we want to display a jsp, tomcat compile it the first time by creating a .java in the folder /work/"name of project" then it compile the .java into a .class
I looked in the /work/project directory and I saw only the old jsp.java but not the new created one.
So I tried to chmod 777 on the /work/project and now tomcat compile my jsp as it should.

But I think this problem will probably come back when I will create a new project... and I don't want to chmod 777 all the directory that tomcat create.

I have to say that I rewrote the startup.sh script before creating the first project/jsp and tomcat successfully created the /work/project/jsp.java for the first one.

What should I do to give all rights to tomcat ?

Comment: I just asked which daemon/script need to be started to get my jsp compiled...

Comment: @MaximeOzenne: You should detail `some problems` and `some scripts`

Comment: I edited my first post